# PHP PDO fetchAll() returns empty array while SELECTing Temporary Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm having the following query, it contains a `Temporary Table`. If I use a `Temporary Table`, it returns an **`EMPTY ARRAY`**. If I removed the `Temporary Table` it returns an appropriate records.

The following `SQL Query` contains a simple query, I just created a `Temporary Table` and inserted some records and I'm doing `SELECT` Query in that `Temporary Table`. I executed the same code in **phpMyAdmin**, it returns an appropriate records, but in **`PDO`** returns an **`EMPTY ARRAY`**.

Sample and Simple SQL Query:

**Case #1**: **With `Temporary Table`** - Returns an **`EMPTY ARRAY`**

```
<?php

$query = <<<SQL

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempContact (
    ContactId int, 
    FirstName varchar(30), 
    LastName varchar(30), 
    IsActiveContact Boolean
);

INSERT INTO TempContact (ContactId, FirstName, LastName, IsActiveContact)
SELECT CT.ContactId, CT.FirstName, CT.LastName, 
    CASE WHEN SL.SalesId IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS IsActiveContact
FROM Contact CT
LEFT JOIN Sales SL ON CT.ContactId = SL.ContactId;

SELECT TC.* FROM TempContact TC;

SQL;

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute() ? $stmt->fetchAll() : null;

?>
```

**Case #2**: **Without `Temporary Table`** - Returns an appropriate records

```
<?php

$query = <<<SQL

SELECT CT.ContactId, CT.FirstName, CT.LastName, 
    CASE WHEN SL.SalesId IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS IsActiveContact
FROM Contact CT
LEFT JOIN Sales SL ON CT.ContactId = SL.ContactId;

SQL;

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute() ? $stmt->fetchAll() : null;

?>
```

My actual code is so complex, due to easy understanding I added this simple query.

I also checked for any error in my Query (Case #1 Query) using `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());`, but it returns an `EMPTY ARRAY` (*i.e., No Error in my Query*);. Moreover its not throwing any `PDOException`.

Kindly assist me, how to get the records from the `Temporary Table SELECT`

Comment: It's "temporary", as in the query you ran, not "temporal", which means something else entirely.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, I changed it to `Temporary Table`

Comment: Sounds a lot less science-fiction now. Much better.

Answer (score 0):

With PDO you're supposed to execute one query at a time. It's not like the SQL console where you can push in a bunch of statements at once.

You're expected to check that each query completed successfully before moving on to the next one. If you split this up into several `prepare`/`execute` pairs it will work as-is. The reason the second succeeds is because it consists of a single statement.

Comment: even though if I'm using multiple statements without `Temporary Table` in a single query with semicolon serperated, it executes and returns records.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Check for errors from PDO.

Comment: `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());` returns an empty array.

Comment: What happens if you [enable exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)?

Comment: The query executes perfectly, its not throwing an exception.

Comment: Then I'm quite confused. PDO isn't supposed to do that, and `TEMPORARY` should have no impact on the success or failure of the query. If you can't dig up some kind of error preventing it from running this is a mystery to me.

Comment: If you have time, kindly reproduce this scenario. Find the solution and share the same...

Comment: I think executing only a single query is a setting you can turn on.  I didn't think it was driver dependent.  For security reasons its best to only execute one at a time.  But I have a drop table and create table command all in one execute with PDO that works fine.

Comment: I am not sure if Queries are considered to be blocking all the time, so it may be that it executes them too fast.  But that is just a wild guess. 

However I think its "Bad Form" to do them in one go.  Makes error checking / response harder.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - I'm using multiple statements in a single query for updating ledger tables in a Cron Job PHP Script, in that I'm using Temporary Table too. Its working fine. If I'm doing SELECT Query in a Temporary Table, its returning ZERO Records.

Comment: You're going to have to do more diagnostic work of your own here. Running multiple statements in PDO in one query is always a bad plan, so split that up and test which one's not working. Try and reproduce the problem on another machine. Eliminate causes systematically.

Comment: @tadman [multiple queries with PDO is all right](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiquery), (at least with mysql), as long as you're switching the emulation on.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's risky to run multiple queries without checking that they've succeeded. Can lead to a bit of a train-wreck if you're always assuming the previous statements were fine.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with that. Though you still can check every query's result even when running several queries in one call.

Answer (score 0):

> PHP PDO fetchAll() returns empty array while SELECTing Temporary Table

*Obviously*, it is not true. Anyone can run the following code utilizing a temporary table and see the result

```
$pdo->query("CREATE temporary TABLE tmptest (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(255))");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tmptest VALUES (NULL, ?)");
foreach (['Sam','Bob','Joe'] as $name)
{
    $stmt->execute([$name]);
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tmptest");
$stmt->execute();

var_export($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR));
```

which outputs the expected

```
array (
  1 => 'Sam',
  2 => 'Bob',
  3 => 'Joe',
)
```

While your problem is coming from the fact that you are running **multiple queries** in a single call and so the first fetchAll() is naturally returns an empty result as the first query returns nothing. To get your data you should be either run your queries in separate statements or [move the internal pointer to the next result](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiquery) and then call for fetchAll():

```
$pdo->query("CREATE temporary TABLE tmptest (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(255))");
$pdo->query("CREATE temporary TABLE tmptest2 (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(255))");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tmptest VALUES (NULL, ?)");
foreach (['Sam','Bob','Joe'] as $name)
{
    $stmt->execute([$name]);
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tmptest2 SELECT * from tmptest;SELECT * FROM tmptest2");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->nextRowset();
var_export($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR));
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. It returns the first statements result.